# PyQt avoid falling in infinite loop when handling an event

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyqt, pyqt5

In PyQt I am trying to get the content of the clipboard every time it changes, do some operations to calculate the output as text and put it again in the clipboard.

The problem seems to be that when I change the content of the clipboard inside the "clipboard content changed" event handling function, this triggers and infinite calling that function over and over again.

This is the code I am using:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QClipboard
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QPlainTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize

class ExampleWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(440, 240))
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 Clipboard example")

        # Add text field
        self.b = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.b.insertPlainText("Use your mouse to copy text to the clipboard.\nText can be copied from any application.\n")
        self.b.move(10,10)
        self.b.resize(400,200)

        # clipboard
        self.cb = QApplication.clipboard()
        self.cb_changed_handler = self.cb.dataChanged.connect(self.clipboardChanged)

    def clipboardChanged(self):
        text = self.cb.text()
        print(text)
        self.b.insertPlainText(text + '\n')
        self.cb.clear(mode=self.cb.Clipboard)
        self.cb.setText("this is a text", mode=self.cb.Clipboard) # this creates an infinite loop!!    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = ExampleWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

I have also tried the following `clipboardChanged` function without success, python crashes:

```
def clipboardChanged(self):
    text = self.cb.text()
    print(text)
    self.b.insertPlainText(text + '\n')
    # This does not work, python crashes!!
    # let's disable the event listener, do what we should and restore the event
    self.cb.dataChanged().disconnect()
    self.cb.clear(mode=self.cb.Clipboard)
    self.cb.setText("this is a text", mode=self.cb.Clipboard)
    self.cb_changed_handler = self.cb.dataChanged.connect(self.clipboardChanged)
```

I am using Windows.

After executing this

```
from PyQt5.Qt import PYQT_VERSION_STR
print("PyQt version:", PYQT_VERSION_STR)
```

I get

```
PyQt version: 5.9.2
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to prevent the QClipBoard [`dataChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html#dataChanged) signal from being emitted in the clipboardChanged method using [`blockSignals()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals):

```
def clipboardChanged(self):
    text = self.cb.text()
    print(text)
    self.b.insertPlainText(text + '\n')
    self.cb.blockSignals(True)
    self.cb.clear(mode=self.cb.Clipboard)
    self.cb.setText("this is a text", mode=QClipboard.Clipboard)   
    self.cb.blockSignals(False)
```

Comment: Your answer seems correct but it also results in a infinite-loop in my computer.  Should I clear any signal queue?

Comment: Are you only using the code you provided? If instead your real code is different from what you provide then your code is not an MRE and it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: Yes, I am using the same code that is shown in the question + replacing the clipboardChanged by the one you proposed in your answer. What additional information may I provide?

Comment: @aturegano That's strange, maybe it's a bug. What version of PyQt5 do you use

Comment: I am using PyQt version: 5.9.2

Comment: @aturegano Try updating it, the latest version is PyQt5 5.13.1

Comment: May you tell me with which version your answer is working, please?

Comment: @aturegano I always use the latest version for my answers.

Comment: At this moment I am not allowed to update the version. I will try to provide more info tomorrow. Thanks for your support.